# system call in C library function

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls

Since the system calls which any library function of C (say printf()) makes is OS dependant , does that imply that we have a different function printf() for different OS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "different", because I can think of at least three levels of difference:

- Interface differences
- High-level code differences
- Machine code differences

The C standard suggests an interface, and this interface is supposed to be respected across the board. This means that for any OS with a C standard library, the OS should show your program an outlet called `printf`, and if your program plugs into it, it can expect it to behave as documented. This means that for all you're concerned, `printf` is the same across the board.

This doesn't mean that `printf` has to be the same piece of code in every standard library. If someone told me to write a `printf` function and told you to write a `printf` function, we could have a different approach, and that would still be fine as long as we both respected the documented behavior. As a matter of fact, for copyright reasons, you can be certain that the code for Windows's `printf` is different from Linux's `printf` code.

And finally, even with the same source code, `printf` would have to be different to accommodate platform differences. You can't expect an x86 `printf` to work on ARM, for instance. And as you noted, you can't expect a Linux `printf` to work on Windows because of platform conventions and system call differences.

So the machine code behind the `printf` outlet will be different, but the point of the standard is to make it work the same.

Comment: So in reality , do we have different code for a printf() function in windows and in linux ??

Comment: Yes their implementations are different.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "`printf` behave differently on different OSes", then the answer is:

- externally (from the user of the function viewpoint) no, its semantics is standardized. That means that a given call to such a function leads to the same results, whatever is the OS.
- internally probably, its implementation is free. That means, that the computation that such a function will really do to produce you the result can be different.